# How to expose the interface of init() from a class via Protocol in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to use generic types in a class via swift protocols:

```swift
public protocol WebSocketType {
    // some interfaces
}

class _Network<WebSocketT: WebSocketType, Configuration: NetworkConfigurationType> {
    // Use the generic type
    let websocket: WebSocketT
    init(host: String, api: String) {
        // do something here...

        // create the instance which will conform the protocol via generic type
        // compilation error: 'WebSocketT' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
        self.websocket = WebSocketT() 
    }
}

// I'll create a class with concrete classes (WebSocket and NetworkConfiguration). 
// I don't have the class `WebSocket` and I'll extend that to conform the protocol `WebSocketType`.
extension WebSocket: WebSocketType {}
typealias Network = _Network<WebSocket, NetworkConfiguration>
let network = Network()
```

I got an error `'WebSocketT' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`, and I added `init()` in the Protocol `WebSocketType`:

```swift
public protocol WebSocketType {
    init()
}
```

Then I got another error `Initializer requirement 'init()' can only be satisfied by a`required`initializer in non-final class 'WebSocket'`.

How can I fix this issue to construct a generic type in a class?

Answer (score 0):

A subclass of `WebSocket` wouldn't have to inherit all of `WebSocket`'s initializer's. Consequently, a subclass of `WebSocket` could fail to conform to `WebSocketType`. The solution is to declare `WebSocket` with `final class WebSocket` so that it cannot be subclassed or to declare `WebSocket`'s initializer as `required init()` so that all subclasses must also provide it. Then, `WebSocket` would conform to `WebSocketType`, thus fixing your issue.